# Flutter, Firebase, can't install gRPC-Core

Tags: flutter, firebase

I tried to add the Firebase feature module to the Flutter project, but the iOS platform failed：

```
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.9.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing Firebase (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.10.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.9.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.11.1)
Installing Libuv-gRPC (0.0.10)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.2.0)
Installing abseil (1.20211102.0)
Installing cloud_firestore (4.8.0)
Installing firebase_core (2.13.1)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.44.0)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.44.0)
\[!\] Error installing gRPC-Core
\[!\] /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/mp/vsjdmtms4vqgfn1frzpnwkmc0000gn/T/d20230608-40286-zsjrqv submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule path 'third_party/abseil-cpp': checked out '215105818dfde3174fe799600bb0f3cae233d0bf'
Submodule path 'third_party/benchmark': checked out '0baacde3618ca617da95375e0af13ce1baadea47'
Submodule path 'third_party/bloaty': checked out '60209eb1ccc34d5deefb002d1b7f37545204f7f2'
Submodule path 'third_party/boringssl-with-bazel': checked out 'b9232f9e27e5668bc0414879dcdedb2a59ea75f2'
Submodule path 'third_party/cares/cares': checked out 'e982924acee7f7313b4baa4ee5ec000c5e373c30'
Submodule path 'third_party/envoy-api': checked out '20b1b5fcee88a20a08b71051a961181839ec7268'
Submodule path 'third_party/googleapis': checked out '2f9af297c84c55c8b871ba4495e01ade42476c92'
Submodule path 'third_party/googletest': checked out 'c9ccac7cb7345901884aabf5d1a786cfa6e2f397'
Submodule path 'third_party/libuv': checked out '02a9e1be252b623ee032a3137c0b0c94afbe6809'
Submodule path 'third_party/opencensus-proto': checked out '4aa53e15cbf1a47bc9087e6cfdca214c1eea4e89'
Submodule path 'third_party/opentelemetry': checked out '60fa8754d890b5c55949a8c68dcfd7ab5c2395df'
Submodule path 'third_party/protobuf': checked out 'cb46755e6405e083b45481f5ea4754b180705529'
Submodule path 'third_party/protoc-gen-validate': checked out '59da36e59fef2267fc2b1849a05159e3ecdf24f3'
Submodule path 'third_party/re2': checked out '8e08f47b11b413302749c0d8b17a1c94777495d5'
Submodule path 'third_party/xds': checked out 'cb28da3451f158a947dfc45090fe92b07b243bc1'
Submodule path 'third_party/zlib': checked out 'cacf7f1d4e3d44d871b605da3b647f07d718623f'
Submodule 'third_party/abseil-cpp' (https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git) registered for path 'third_party/abseil-cpp'
```

I've upgraded Flutter to the latest version and looked up a lot of solutions, but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you find any solutions ..?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, you seem to have had a connection issue to github.com.